# SEO friendly .htaccess RuleRewrites

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, seo

I'm using a piece of e-commerce software that has product categories and the links are like:
`http://www.mysitename.com/mycategory--c7.html`

Is there an easy way to remove the "--c7" or whatever identifier it produces?

This a chunk of what I found in .htacccess:

```
#cre SEO reformat for pages.html pages
RewriteRule ^pd([0-9]+_?[0-9]*)-(.*)\.html$ pages.php?pID=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/c([^/]*)/p([0-9]+_?[0-9]*)/(.*)/pages\.html$ pages.php?cID=$2&pID=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/c([^/]*)/pages\.html$ pages.php?cID=$2 [QSA,L]
```

and I don't really know the notation so explain your answer just a little.

Comment: These rules do not pertain to the `mycategory--c7` link you've shown. And doing modifications there would require adapting the code anyway. If this is used in a commercial setting, then hire a freelancer to look it over if you are unversed (we don't do tutoring here).

Comment: I'm a programmer but I don't play in .htaccess much.. and yes that it the part that touches the categories as it's the only part that writes 'c' URLs.. I'm not asking for tutorials..

Comment: None of those rules will ever rewrite the URI: `/mycategory--c7.html`. What do you mean by "remove"? Internally remove it so the resource `/mycategory.html` gets served? Externally redirect the client to `/mycategory.html` and then serve `/mycategory.html` when the client re-requests it?

Comment: Which "piece of e-commerce software" do you use?

Comment: CRE Loaded Commerce software.. and so the URL is like site.com/hats--c12.html for SEO purposes I am looking to rewrite it to just site.com/hats.html

Comment: Do you believe this URL structure hurts your SEO?

Comment: @nickhar - Google's docs: http://tinyurl.com/9odwla8 CRE provides this, which is where the OP got his example from: http://tinyurl.com/8d66fu7 - the URLs are friendly. that -- is a separator in parsing where it will be left with category and c7 and not necessarily the grouping of the two, but it will be considered. My suggestion is the url structure at that level is merely personal preference. If he doesn't like looking at them, then ok get rid of them. But the only way you would be "hurt" by this url structure is if your content was irrelevant and you failed at every other aspect of SEO.

Comment: @KaiQing Fair point. Agree on your last point too!

Answer (score 2):

Check URL rewrites for .htaccess. That is where you want to focus, but it might take some work, so be prepared.

Comment: I think he's looking for an example rather than how much work is going to be involved.